# How Can I Update Component Status on Page Reload Using Nuxt/Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building a "Nav/Progress Bar" component which shows users how far along in the application flow they are, using Nuxt.js with Bootstrap-Vue. The progress bar works fine when the user follows a `<nuxt-link>` to the next page. However, if the user reloads the page, the progress bar will reset to its default state.

As you can see in the example below, I'm using a Vue watcher to update the progress bar on an update to the page route. However, this watcher does not work when a page is reloaded (I assume this is because, on reloading a page, the page route *does not change*). But how else could I force the progress bar to load the current status?

I have a feeling the solution should be pretty simple, but I'm at a loss. I'm new to Vue, so please excuse me if I've missed anything obvious. Thanks!

[Image of progress bar on Page One - "Page One Appearance"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zlz2.jpg)

[Image of progress bar on Page Two - "Page Two Appearance"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJu9p.jpg)

Here is my HTML `<template>`:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <b-link to="/" v-bind:class="{ 'font-weight-bold text-primary':   pageOneActive, 'text-secondary font-weight-normal':   pageOneInactive }" >
          Build
        </b-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b-link v-bind:to="reviewLink" v-bind:class="{ 'font-weight-bold text-primary': pageTwoActive, 'text-secondary font-weight-normal': pageTwoInactive }" >
          Review
        </b-link>
      </div>
    </div>

    <b-progress :max="2">
      <b-progress-bar :value="progressIndicator"></b-progress-bar>
    </b-progress>

  </div>
</template>
```

And my `<script` looks like this:

```
<script>
import Bootstrap from "bootstrap-vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageName: this.$nuxt.$route.name,
      progressIndicator: 1,
      progressSuccess: 0,
      pageOneActive: true,
      pageOneInactive: false,
      pageTwoActive: false,
      pageTwoInactive: true,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    "$route.path": function() {
      let pageName = "index";
      let progressIndicator = 1;
      let progressSuccess = 0;
      let pageOneActive = null;
      let pageOneInactive = null;
      let pageTwoActive = null;
      let pageTwoInactive = null;

      function setPageInactive() {
        pageOneActive = false;
        pageOneInactive = true;
        pageTwoActive = false;
        pageTwoInactive = true;
      }

      pageName = this.$nuxt.$route.name;
      console.log(pageName);

      if (pageName === "index") {
        setPageInactive();
        progressIndicator = 1;
        pageOneActive = true;
        pageOneInactive = false;
      } else if (pageName === "review") {
        setPageInactive();
        progressIndicator = 2;
        pageTwoActive = true;
        pageTwoInactive = false;
      }

      console.log(progressIndicator);
      
      this.progressIndicator = progressIndicator;
      this.progressSuccess = progressSuccess;
      this.pageOneActive = pageOneActive;
      this.pageOneInactive = pageOneInactive;
      this.pageTwoActive = pageTwoActive;
      this.pageTwoInactive = pageTwoInactive;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*(I know this is not the most efficient way to do things, with Inactive + Active variables, vs basing the css changes on one variable change. I just haven't had the time to change it yet.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the progress bar resets to its default state, when the user reloads the page, is because in the `data` property, the progress indicator is `1`. Reloading the page "resets" the data properties to their default values.

However, you can capture the values on reload using the `created/mounted` lifecycle hook. Here, I decided to use the mounted hook. You make the same checks you made in the `watcher`. In order to avoid duplication, I extracted it into a function and removed redundant code. You can restore them to their original condition, if you please. The idea is the same.

Let your `script` section be something like this:

```js
<script>
import Bootstrap from "bootstrap-vue";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageName: '',
      progressIndicator: 0,
      pageOneActive: true,
      pageTwoActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    determinePageProgressIndicator() {
      this.pageName = this.$nuxt.$route.name;
      this.progressIndicator = this.pageName === "index" ? 1 : 2  // this is ok now as there are only two page names. If there are more, the logic will be more complex.
      this.pageOneActive = this.pageName === 'index';
      this.pageTwoActive = this.pageName === 'review';
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.determinePageProgressIndicator();
  },
  watch: {
    "$route.path": function() {
      this.determinePageProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

You don't need `pageOneInactive` and `pageTwoInactive` as in JavaScript, you can determine these using the logical NOT (!) operator.

If you know `pageOneActive = true`, then you can replace `pageOneInactive with !pageOneActive`. The logical NOT operator will evaluate the expression to false.

You can read more about the logical NOT operator [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT);

In your `template`, you then do

```html
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <b-link to="/" v-bind:class="{ 'font-weight-bold text-primary':   pageOneActive, 'text-secondary font-weight-normal':   !pageOneActive }" > // replace pageOneInactive
          Build
        </b-link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b-link v-bind:to="reviewLink" v-bind:class="{ 'font-weight-bold text-primary': pageTwoActive, 'text-secondary font-weight-normal': !pageTwoActive }" > // replace pageTwoInactive
          Review
        </b-link>
      </div>
    </div>

    <b-progress :max="2">
      <b-progress-bar :value="progressIndicator"></b-progress-bar>
    </b-progress>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you Tony. A lot of things “clicked” for me after reading your answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: I am happy to help. :)